# What are macros in class definitions and function signatures for?

Tags: c++, api, class, macros, signature

When looking at source code for libraries in C++ I often see things like this:

```
#define API_MACRO

class API_MACRO className
{
    //Class stuff
};
```

In addition I see things like the following with method signatures:

```
void API_MACRO functionName();
```

So my question is what is this for and what is this practice called? I tried looking it up online but found nothing. It doesn't seem to offer any benefit or practical use...especially since these functions and classes are already wrapped up inside of namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you make your function or class show up for public use in a Unix shared library or a Windows DLL?

Each one has its own method. Luckily they are similar enough that a macro can handle it.

For GCC you want
`#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))`

For Windows MSVC you want
`#define DLLEXPORT __declspec( dllexport )`

And if you are linking to a DLL in Windows you need the definitions to be marked
`#define DLLEXPORT __declspec( dllimport )`

Those lines above were copied from a project of mine and `API_MACRO` may be a better name, because `DLLEXPORT` doesn't make a lot of sense when importing.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I mostly do development on mac and so have never needed to   do this before. Thank you.

Comment: @user1782677: I am not sure about how XCode sets things up for library builds, but for any serious library work you want to hide all of the internals by default and only show the external API functions. Both GCC and LLVM Clang have `-fvisibility=hidden` and I found this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html

Answer (score 1):

The API_MACRO is conditionally defined. Typically in this usage, it is defined as `__declspec(dllimport)` or `__declspec(dllexport)`, or nothing at all when not using MSVC's dynamic linking language extension for whatever reason.

Thus, the definition would usually be found in the build system, which determines whether it's being built under Windows as consuming or building the DLL.